# Distributing playing cards to n players

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with the code in **Python**.

What I wish to do is I have playing cards which can be any number (17, 41, 52, 105, 200, etc.). I have to take user input to get the number of players. Then, I have to distribute the playing cards among those players. I get it that not every player will get equal number of cards (which is fine).

Finally, I have to display those cards that have been given to the players. The place where I am stuck is how-to automatically generate lists with unique names depending on the number of players that the user gives.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: I believe you could use an array.

Comment: @MarthyM Python does not have arrays.

Comment: @KlausD. well, in python a list serves the same function.

Answer (score 0):

this will get you started, (but only started. you really need to show us what you have done): You can start with a master list of names and then depending on user input, select that many from the list and use a dict comprehension to create a players dict. Maybe something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import shuffle

name_list = 'a b c d e f g h i j k'.split()
shuffle(name_list)
num_players = int(input("How many players? "))
players = { name: [] for name in name_list[:num_players] }
```

From there you deal the cards and populate the appropriate players dict item. That part should be fairly easy. If you get stuck ask for more help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, David!  I did it on my own. If you wish, I can share the code with you.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
No_of_Players = int(raw_input("Enter Number os Players : "))
#You can put any number in the place of No_of_Players and provide your range as per requirement
list_RandomNum = random.sample(range(1, 100), No_of_Players)
print(list_RandomNum)
```

Comment: Your code purely does what is described in the question.